# NSDictionnary entry to object

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary, fmdb

Is there an easy way to put an NSDictionnary entry into an object ?

From my database, I fecth an entry of NSDictionnary as :

```
columnName1 = contentOfColumName1
columnName2 = contentOfColumName2
columnName3 = contentOfColumName3
....
```

I would like to instanciate an object which has n fields : columnName1, columnName2, columnName3 (same names than the NSDictionnary entry's keys

This is what I would prefer to avoid ...

```
MyObject* o = [[MyObject alloc] init]
[o setColumName1 = myNsDictionnary entry's value for key 'column1']
[o setColumName2 = myNsDictionnary entry's value for key 'column2']
[o setColumName3 = myNsDictionnary entry's value for key 'column3']
...
```

Thanks

Comment: I've found `[myObject enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
            [myObject setValue:obj forKey:(NSString *)key];
        }];` Is that a good practice ?

Comment: Yes, that's Key-Value Coding (KVC).  Check out the docs.

Comment: creating a model class to hold the data could also be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this `[myObject setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:myNsDictionnary];`?